# Mongodb installation and configuration with zip

Tags: mongodb, mongodb4.0

I downloaded mongodb from [here](http://downloads.mongodb.org/win32/mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-ssl-debugsymbols-v4.0-latest.zip). When I unzip it only has 3 *.pdb. How can I use them and how can i create replica sets.

**UPDATE**

In mongodb 4 how can i create replicasets ?

Comment: Those are the debug symbols. Try the [installer](http://downloads.mongodb.org/win32/mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-ssl-v4.0-latest-signed.msi) instead.

Comment: what is a debug symbols please ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694900/can-you-explain-whats-symbols-and-debug-symbols-in-c-world